# How to find the Domain for this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, radicals

[image]

my working out:

- x+a>0
- x>-a
- x^2-a^2 > 0
- x>|a|
- a^2-x^2>0
- |a|>x

hmm.. the answer is b ... how, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rational function with square roots, so there are two important things to consider.

First off, the denominator cannot equal $0$. Secondly, the value under the radical must be non-negative.

So looking at the denominator, you know that $x\neq -a$.

Looking at the square roots, you need $x^2-a^2\geq 0$ and $a^2-x^2\geq 0\\\implies a^2=x^2.$

Now taking into account that $x\neq -a$, solve $a^2=x^2$.

$x^2=a^2\implies x=\pm a$,

but because of the denominator, we said $x\neq -a$.

Hence $D=\{a\}$.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could have helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at the top. You need 
$$
x^2 - a^2\ge 0\\
x^2 - a^2\le 0,
$$hence $x^2 = a^2$.

Now look at the bottom: you need $x+a\neq 0$.

Comment: than you, this helped :)